# Why is box not wrapping image element properly in html?

Tags: html, css

Hello – new to html and learning CSS as I go so I'm sure this is an obvious error. Looking for a simple fix. Essentially I have written very simple CSS so that a box surrounds links when hovering - this works great for text links so far.

```
a:hover {
    color: rgb(203, 173, 126); 
    border: 1px solid rgb(203, 173, 126);
    padding: 2px;
}
```

But if I am using an image to link things get tricky. By default the box just highlights the bottom of the image, ignoring the borders altogether. I know this has something to do with display: inline-block, but when I write that into the style then when hovering over the image the box wraps correctly around the top and bottom margins, but stretches all the way to the left and right side of the page.

```
<a href="youtube.com" style="display: inline-block;">
    <img src="image.png" width="30%" height="30%">
</a>
```

I found a forum ([here](https://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/53850-css-border-on-hover-does-not-wrap-images/)) where it looks like someone else was having the exact same problem but I cannot see how they ultimately fixed it, even as I have tried to go through their responses. Wondering if someone could help me for my case!

Comment: Because your *hovering* is a link, not the image. If you do ```img:hover {..}```, you will see the difference.

Comment: That worked but I'm still getting the problematic hover from the a:hover on top of the correct img:hover. Is there a way I can negate the a:hover on images? So that it only applies to text. @Newbee

Comment: I don't know the structure of your code and hard to tell if it's actually gonna work, so I will post an answer to give a demo. If it's different or not useful, please tell so I will delete my answer. tnx.

Comment: That's a smart solution. The workaround I decided is not to use the parent CSS style for this specific page with clickable images and to modify it like you showed. Working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether where the animation will take effect.

Applying `hover` to the *parent* will apply also to it's *child*, so you need to consider it.

```css
span:hover, img:hover {
    color: rgb(203, 173, 126);
    border: 1px solid rgb(203, 173, 126);
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="youtube.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="30%" height="30%">
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <span>THIS TEXT IS A LINK.</span>
  </a>
</div>
```